# The subgroups of $D_6$ of order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $D_6=\{e,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5,a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,ar^4,ar^5\}$ where $r^6 = 1$ and $a^2=1$.

I am confused as to how we find the subgroups of order $2$ other than the center subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Each (non-trivial) element has one of two forms, either $r^i$ or $ar^i$. A subgroup of order 2 must be generated by an element of order 2, so we want to find the elements $x$ such that $x^2=1$. The following hints will help you (they essentially answer the question!).

**Hint 1**: $(r^i)^2=r^{2i\pmod 6}$. So $2i=0\pmod6\Rightarrow i=$...?

**Hint 2**: The product $ara=r^{-1}$ (why?). So $ar^iar^i=$...?

Comment: The center is (id,r^3) other than that, I have no idea

Comment: @JessyWhite I have edited my answer to include all of the cases. Please let me know if you need any clarification.